# How can I use filter functions (exceptall...) on a calculation table without relationship to a date table?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm using a calculation table (hr_data) and a date table without any relationship between the two of them. As a matter of consequence, using the RELATED function is not a possibility.

I would like to perform a measure which would measure the % of total.

To do so, I would need to use the following function:

```
% of Total_HR = DIVIDE (
        [Count of Active Employee],
        CALCULATE(
                    [Count of Active Employee],
                    ALLEXCEPT(hr_data, hr_data[team], hr_data[company], hr_data[employee_type], hr_data[gender], hr_data[grade], hr_data[total_experience], hr_data[education], hr_data[XP])))
```

And on top of this, I would need to remove the filter on the date, but I can't because the date is not part of the hr_data table.

How could I proceed, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ALL` function in conjunction with your measure:

```
% of Total_HR =
DIVIDE (
    [Count of Active Employee],
    CALCULATE(
        [Count of Active Employee],
        ALLEXCEPT(
            hr_data,
            hr_data[team],
            hr_data[company],
            hr_data[employee_type],
            hr_data[gender],
            hr_data[grade],
            hr_data[total_experience],
            hr_data[education],
            hr_data[XP]
        ),
        ALL('DateTable')  // Change it with the your calendar table
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi Amira,
Thanks for your answer.
Unfortunately, still doesn't work with this trick. I have also tried ALL('Date'[Year Month]) but no luck either :(

Comment: Can you share your model ? pbix file ?

Comment: Actually you were right, I managed to find my way by adjusting the content within ALLEXCEPT(), thanks a lot Amira!

Comment: If my answer helped you don't forget to accept it :)